# How can I validate SMTP hostname/port/username/password is working on Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, smtp

I have a node.js web application and I'd like its status page to have an indicator if the SMTP settings for the site are functioning.  I could send an email and check if it goes across, but I'm wondering if I can do something like a ping for SMTP.  Can I, without actually sending an email, check that I can connect to the SMTP server and verify the configured credentials?

I did a little experimenting with the smtp-protocol module (https://npmjs.org/package/smtp-protocol) but was not successful as I couldn't figure out how to use a username/password with the client.

Comment: It's a very simple protocol that's well documented. You could sign in as the user and disconnect. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995718(v=exchg.65).aspx

Comment: That library you pointed at also has a `login` method. I'd imagine you'd `connect`, `helo` then call `login`?

Answer (score 1):

Make verification method by sending email using that current credentials. if email can be sent then by that credentials then it is working fine otherwise it will be incorrect credentials. if it is correct credentials then use it for email sending process